# button in Excel to copy information from one sheet to another on a new row

Tags: excel, macros

Very new to macros and this is my first one...

So Im building a an excel form where we would enter information(UpScoreAudit), click a button and that information would be copied to another sheet(UpScores) on the same workbook, on a new row. I've searched on here, and found some help, but nothing happens when I click on the button. This is what I have currently:

```
Sub OnClick()
Dim refTable As Variant, trans As Variant
refTable = Array("A=C3", "B=C4", "C=C5", "D=C6", "E=C7", "F=C9", "G=D11", "H=D13", "J=E15")
Dim Row As Long
Row = Worksheets("UpScores").UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
For Each trans In refTable
    Dim Dest As String, Field As String
    Dest = Trim(Left(trans, InStr(1, trans, "=") - 1)) & Row
    Field = Trim(Right(trans, Len(trans) - InStr(1, trans, "=")))
    Worksheets("UpScoreAudit").Range(Dest).Value = Worksheets("UpScores").Range(Field).Value
Next
End Sub
```

Any help is great appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try naming your sub CommandButton1_Click() where CommandButton1 is the name of your button

Comment: still not getting anything.